# How do I make a custom Ubuntu cd,using KDE as the desktop interface ?

Tags: installation, gnome, kde, iso, custom-distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

I would like to create _custom Ubuntu cd by myself....please don't redirect me to [kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/)...

Comment: this Might help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization   I have made many Linux CDs using it

Comment: the best answer so far is the comment above

Answer (score 1):

What about your task makes you need to use an .iso? If you want to install Kde you can install the package:

```
kubuntu-desktop
```

This can be done via:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

After this has installed logout and select Kubuntu or Kde or something like that from the list of desktop next to your name where you enter your password.

Comment: I guess i mentioned, i want to **build my own** custom .iso
and actually i know to use apt-get.....**EASY WAY**